# Angular 4 : Unterminated regular expression literal

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning angular and i've created a registration component but I have the following error :

> registration.component.ts (4,19): Unterminated regular expression literal.

**/app/registration/registration.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from ‘@angular/core’;
@Component({
     selector : ‘app-registration’,
     templateUrl : ‘./registration.component.html’,
     styleUrls : [‘./registration.component.css’]
})
export class RegistrationComponent{}
```

**/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from 
'./registration/registration.component';

 @NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   RegistrationComponent
],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   FormsModule
],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I need to understand where is my error and why the compile failed thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its `‘` operator error :

replace this `‘` with  `'`.

---

From this :

```
import { Component } from ‘@angular/core’;
...
selector : ‘app-registration’,
templateUrl : ‘./registration.component.html’,
styleUrls : [‘./registration.component.css’]
```

To

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
...
selector : 'app-registration',
templateUrl : './registration.component.html',
styleUrls : ['./registration.component.css']
```

Comment: Ok thank you, you fixed my problem, I'll keep that in my mind